# How do I insert a case-sensitive string into Mysql using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlalchemy to insert data into a mysql database.

I am trying to insert uppercase strings and mixed case strings but the entries do not keep the right case.

```
class Key(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Key'
    key_name = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True)
    key_id = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    secret_key = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)

Python Console
>>>key = Key('MyKey','JADFHLAKDFHAJ','FHjkdshfKSJFSdfkhsDDFK')

>>>key.key_name

'Mykey'

>>>key.key_id

'Jadfhlakdfhaj'

>>>key.secret_key

'Fhjkdshfksjfsdfkhsddfk'
```

How can I keep the case persistent when inserting these values?

As a side note, when I insert these values directly into mysql using an insert statement the casing of the letters is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Amateur mistake on my part. I had the following code in the **init** function.

```
def __init__(self, key_name, key_id, secret_key, user):
    self.key_name = key_name
    self.key_id = key_id.title()
    self.secret_key = secret_key.title()
    self.user = user
```

The '.title()' function was what was changing the casing of strings.